# error occurring at & line

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Code:

```
DECLARE
NAME VARCHAR2(20);
begin
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('enter the name');
NAME := &NAME1;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(name);
end;
```

An error is occurring in it ? what is the error I am using sql developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use quotes for bind variables of type string :

```
DECLARE
NAME VARCHAR2(20);
begin
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('enter the name');
NAME := '&NAME1';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(name); -- by the way, i assume your serveroutput option is on, if not just issue "set serveroutput on" before this statement.
end;
/
```

When prompted *Enter Value for NAME1* you need to enter the name without quotes of course. e.g. enter `JOHN` instead of `'JOHN'` when prompted for a name value.

Comment: That is one half of the answer. The other half is that the OP can also put the quotes in the value passed to the substitution variable. When prompted for a name, the user can enter `'JOHN'` instead of `JOHN` (which will not work if there are no single quotes in the PL/SQL code). Either one solution or the other will work; each is probably the better choice in different situations.